# How to tell if a STEAM ID is taken using nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, steam

I am trying to make a function that can tell me information about a steam page that I can use to tell if the profile was found or not, and perform an action accordingly.

What I came up with is the function below. This tells me a bunch of information about the page and I was hoping that when the steam profile is not found the status would be 404, but there is no difference between a profile that is found and one that isnt.

```
//GETHTML
function getURLInfo(url) {



   (fetch(url))
                            .then(res => console.log(res))
                            .then(body => console.log(body)) 

      }
```

*THIS IS THE CONSOLE OUTPUT*

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: Gunzip {
      _writeState: [Uint32Array],
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _transformState: [Object],
      _hadError: false,
      bytesWritten: 0,
      _handle: [Zlib],
      _outBuffer: <Buffer 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0d 0a 3c 68 74 6d 6c 20 63 6c 61 73 73 3d 22 20 72 65 73 70 6f 6e 73 69 76 65 22 20 6c 61 6e 67 3d 22 65 ... 16334 more bytes>,
      _outOffset: 0,
      _chunkSize: 16384,
      _defaultFlushFlag: 2,
      _finishFlushFlag: 2,
      _defaultFullFlushFlag: 3,
      _info: undefined,
      _level: -1,
      _strategy: 0,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/cmm9/',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

What I thought about trying is creating a function that makes the HTML of the page a long string, and then if the string includes 'Specified profile could not be found.' perform an action, but I don't know how I would do that. I need help on how to do this.

Comment: Can you share one of the URLs that you're hitting with your request?

Comment: profile that doesnt exist: https://steamcommunity.com/id/cmm9/  profile that does exist: https://steamcommunity.com/id/n83/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should really be using is the Steam Web API. You can register for a key here: https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey

Here's a valid request: https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v2/?key={KEYGOESHERE}&format=json&steamids=76561198036370701

```
{
    "response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561198036370701",
                "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
                "profilestate": 1,
                "personaname": "Heavenanvil",
                "commentpermission": 1,
                "profileurl": "https://steamcommunity.com/id/heavenanvil/",
                "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d9/d9838736a062d18eb6848ba8d5cc56d72c1cef80.jpg",
                "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d9/d9838736a062d18eb6848ba8d5cc56d72c1cef80_medium.jpg",
                "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d9/d9838736a062d18eb6848ba8d5cc56d72c1cef80_full.jpg",
                "avatarhash": "d9838736a062d18eb6848ba8d5cc56d72c1cef80",
                "personastate": 0,
                "realname": "Heaven",
                "primaryclanid": "103582791433464576",
                "timecreated": 1294227386,
                "personastateflags": 0,
                "loccountrycode": "RU",
                "locstatecode": "39",
                "loccityid": 40975
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And when there's no matching steamIds, you get an empty respoonse.

```
{
    "response": {
        "players": []
    }
}
```

More documentation on the API can be found here: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview

Edit: If you want to check to see if there are any players that were returned, just check the `response.players` array.

fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        const { response } = json;
        if (response.players && response.players.length > 0) {
            // There are players that were found. Do something.
        } else {
            // No players found, do something else.
        }
    });

If you want to check using their VanityURL, you can use this endpoint: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key={KEYGOESHERE}&format=json&vanityurl=Eclyps19

Success Response:

```
{
    "response": {
        "steamid": "76561197960670951",
        "success": 1
    }
}
```

Not Found Respoonse:

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 42,
        "message": "No match"
    }
}
```

To check this for a success:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        const { response } = json;
        if (response.success === 1) {
            // Player found. Do something.
        } else {
            // No player found, do something else.
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Can I search using the profileurl too? Also, what if I wanted an action to be performed when the response is empty?

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to check the players array for values. Also edited the API key URL with the correct one.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what I wanted to achieve, but is there a way to find the same information using the profile url instead of the steamid? Just an extra, and thanks!

Comment: If anyone is wondering, I found a way to get the same information using the profile url!

http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&vanityurl=userVanityUrlName
(replace uservanityurlname with the profile url)

Comment: Updated answer using the vanityURL

Comment: Thanks for everything Alec, I was just implementing your code and i got the error (JS) Expression not found at .then(...). Any idea what this could mean?

Comment: Give the new code at the bottom a shot. It checks the payload using the vanityURL for a success value of 1.

Comment: I ran the code and added console.log('this is a test') on both instances and the output is this error: (node:14088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
EDIT: nevermind! that was something to do with my other code which was wrong